# Is there any XML editor for textarea

Tags: 7

I want to insert XML editor for text area. Is it possible?

Currently Is there any XML data editors. If there is no XML editor for text area what is the possible way .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [XML Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/xml_field) module

> Defines an xml field type. Provides an XML widget using CodeMirror (beginning with version 7.x-1.6).Provides XML related API functions for working with XML code. Adds a theme_xml() theme function. Defines a form type called xmltext for use in the Forms API.

Image from project page

[image]

Comment: tq. How can i reach you mr.Krishna Mohan . I want to learn drupal

Comment: Thanks, but I'm full time developer for an organization. So I think I can't help you :) I spend  here whenever I get some free time. BTW I'm not Drupal Expert like you think. :) I still feel I'm a beginner to Drupal ;)